# Unable to generate path to save image in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I created a delegate on iOS (it works on Android) to save an image using the  `CrossDownloadManager` plugin.  I copied the code from the Xamarin documentation but when I run the method, "path" returns an empty string:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using YHTS.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ImageSaver_IOS))]

namespace YHTS.iOS
{
    public class ImageSaver_IOS : IImageSaver
    {
        public ImageSaver_IOS() { }

        public string Save(string imageName)
        {
            string fileName = (new NSUrl(imageName, false)).LastPathComponent;
            string path =  Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), fileName);
            return path;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" - what does that mean?  Do you get an error or exception?  Does the app crash?  Does your computer burst into flames?  Have you tried to use the debugger to trace the flow of execution?

Comment: I'm sorry,  I've never been able to step through code and hitting breakpoints when debugging my iOS app.  When I run the method, "path" returns an empty string.

Comment: if you can't get the debugger to work, then try putting Debug.Writelines after each statement to check the inputs and outputs.  And break all of the compound statements up until you get this sorted out.

Comment: What is the value of imageName?

Comment: imageName = "YHTS" + DateTime.Today.Ticks.ToString() + ".jpg"

Comment: if URL cannot find your image it probably will return LastPathComponent as NULL. In such case Path.Combine will return empty string. check what is  returned fileName. Why you are using LastPathComponent?

Comment: Actually based on the Debug.Writelines this delegate is never even run.  The identical one for Android runs.